# I want to create a remote thread and after that I want to read his result

Tags: delphi

In the code below I would like to read the result from LoadLibrayA, that was created by a CreateRemoteThread.

I will be grateful for the help,
because it seems to be impossible,

Maybe the result is free in time to read,
any suggestion will be receive with happiness

```
procedure InjectDLL(hProcess : Cardinal; ADllPath : String);
var
  lSize : Cardinal;

  hThread : Cardinal;
  szLibPath : array [0..MAX_PATH] of char;

  pLibRemote : Pointer;
  hLibModule : DWORD  ;

  hKernel32 : HMODULE;
begin
  hKernel32 := GetModuleHandle('Kernel32.dll');

  FillMemory(@szLibPath, sizeOf(szLibPath), 0);
  CopyMemory(@szLibPath, Pointer(ADllPath), length(ADllPath));

  pLibRemote :=
    VirtualAllocEx(
      hProcess,
      nil,
      sizeOf(szLibPath),
      MEM_COMMIT,
      PAGE_READWRITE
    );

  try
    WriteProcessMemory(
      hProcess,
      pLibRemote,
      @szLibPath,
      sizeOf(szLibPath),
      lSize
    );

    hThread :=
      CreateRemoteThread(
        hProcess,
        nil,
        0,
        GetProcAddress(hKernel32, 'LoadLibraryA'),
        pLibRemote,
        0,
        lSize
      );

    try
      WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

//------------> HERE I WANT TO READ LoadLibraryA RESULT

      GetExitCodeThread(hThread, hLibModule);
    finally
      // Clean up
      CloseHandle(hThread);
    end;

  finally
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pLibRemote, sizeof(szLibPath), MEM_RELEASE);
  end;
```

Comment: You are performing precisely no error checking at all. Add error checking for each api call. Read the docs to learn how to do that. And tell us the outcome. Which is the function that fails. What is the error. Also, what is `char`? Is is `AnsiChar` or `WideChar`?

Comment: I just dont know how to read the result, I got no errors. in a place of "//------------> HERE I WANT TO READ LoadLibraryA RESULT" I want to read the result of loadlibrary, the result will be cardinal.

Comment: You did not check for errors. So, naturally, you found none. Please check for errors with your API calls. Do you know what I mean when I say that? And once again, what is `char`? The details matter. Finally, what do you mean by "the result of `LoadLibrary`"?

Comment: Ok, dont need to check errors, that is a sample, all I want is a way to read the response memory from CreateRemoteThread. And Char is a variable type that represent a letter, what else? The result of Load library is the return from that function that is called from CreateRemoteThread in some process

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, do you know well delphi?

Comment: Is `char` in your Delphi `AnsiChar` or `WideChar`. In other words, which version of Delphi?

Comment: @Paolo Er, yes, I'd say I was quite knowledgeable about Delphi. And I am very familiar with CreateRemoteThread injection. I have a tool that does that.

Comment: AnsiChar. The resturn is not passes to me but, if there is a way to read from process memmory?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you think is that possible, to read that result from LoadLibreay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thread procedure is `LoadLibrary`. The return value of your thread procedure is the thread's exit code. So the return value of the call to `LoadLibrary` can be read by calling `GetExitCodeThread`. Which you already do.

Comment: realy, you mean GetExitCodeThread is the handle of the module loaded by  LoadLibrary?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But you cannot do anything with it apart from in the remote process.

Comment: I´ll test this tomorow because are all closing, but if you get sure to me I can mark that question as resolved?

Comment: You can see that what I say is correct by reading the `ThreadProc` docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736(v=vs.85).aspx